# Where is Jenkins CLI .jar file stored on the server?

Tags: jenkins

I am using the Jenkins CLI in a script for some Jenkins automation (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/).

According to the docs, you have to first download the .jar from the Jenkins host.

Currently I am doing this by running `wget http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar`

However I would like to reduce the amount of steps in my script, so I would like to skip that download step and just find the `jenkins-cli.jar` directly on the Jenkins server instead of downloading it first.

I tried running `find / -name "jenkins-cli.jar"` to no success.

Does anyone know where it's stored? Surely it must exist somewhere since you can download it direct from the Jenkins host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is packed inside the Jenkins WAR file, along with other jars.

Comment: Well I guess that explains why I couldn't find it on the server. Thanks